# ¿Cómo retorno el nombre de una tabla desde una función?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla llamada *bitacora*:

```
create table bitacora (
        id_bitacora bigserial primary key,
        fecha timestamp not null,
        usuario varchar(50) not null,
        operacion varchar(10) not null ,
        tabla varchar(50) not null ,
        direccion_ip varchar(30) not null ,
        nuevo json,
        viejo json
        );
```

Y necesito que en el atributo *tabla* me muestre o regrese el nombre de la tabla en que se hizo un insert, delete o update. Mi función es la siguiente:

```
create or replace function bitacora_all() returns trigger
as
    $$
    DECLARE
        v_viejo json;
        v_nuevo json;
        v_usuario varchar(100);
        v_ip varchar(100);

    BEGIN
        select current_user::varchar into v_usuario;
        select inet_client_addr()::varchar into v_ip;

        if tg_op = 'INSERT' then
            v_nuevo=to_json(new);
            insert into bitacora(operacion, fecha, usuario, direccion_ip, nuevo)
            VALUES (tg_op,now(),v_usuario,v_ip,v_nuevo);
            return new;
        end if;
        if tg_op = 'DELETE' then
            v_viejo=to_json(old);
            insert into bitacora(operacion, fecha, usuario, direccion_ip, nuevo, viejo)
            VALUES (tg_op,now(),v_usuario,v_ip,v_viejo);
            return old;
        end if;
        if tg_op = 'UPDATE' then
            v_nuevo=to_json(new);
            v_viejo=to_json(old);
            insert into bitacora(operacion, fecha, usuario, direccion_ip, nuevo, viejo)
            VALUES (tg_op,now(),v_usuario,v_ip,v_nuevo,v_viejo);
            return new;
        end if;
        return new;
    end;
    $$language plpgsql;
```

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que me la registre?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar argumentos al disparador. Estos no se declaran, sino que se obtienen a través del arreglo TG_ARGV. en tu disparador `bitacora_all` agrega una variable `v_tabla` y asígnale el primer elemento de este arreglo. Luego úsalo en cada uno de los `INSERT`:

```
create or replace function bitacora_all() returns trigger
as
    $$
    DECLARE
        v_viejo json;
        v_nuevo json;
        v_usuario varchar(100);
        v_ip varchar(100);
        v_tabla varchar(50) := TG_ARGV[0];

    BEGIN
        select current_user::varchar into v_usuario;
        select inet_client_addr()::varchar into v_ip;

        if tg_op = 'INSERT' then
            v_nuevo=to_json(new);
            insert into bitacora(tabla, operacion, fecha, usuario, direccion_ip, nuevo)
            VALUES (v_tabla, tg_op,now(),v_usuario,v_ip,v_nuevo);
            return new;
        end if;
        if tg_op = 'DELETE' then
            v_viejo=to_json(old);
            insert into bitacora(tabla, operacion, fecha, usuario, direccion_ip, nuevo, viejo)
            VALUES (v_tabla, tg_op,now(),v_usuario,v_ip,v_viejo);
            return old;
        end if;
        if tg_op = 'UPDATE' then
            v_nuevo=to_json(new);
            v_viejo=to_json(old);
            insert into bitacora(tabla, operacion, fecha, usuario, direccion_ip, nuevo, viejo)
            VALUES (v_tabla, tg_op,now(),v_usuario,v_ip,v_nuevo,v_viejo);
            return new;
        end if;
        return new;
    end;
    $$language plpgsql;
```

Cuando asocies el disparador a alguna tabla, agrégale como argumento su nombre. Por ejemplo, si lo vas a asociar a la tabla `prueba`, tendrías algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bitacora_prueba AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON prueba EXECUTE PROCEDURE bitacora_all('prueba');
```

Comment: Se necesita una explicación; si no es entrar a descifrar.